Can Adjective clause modify a sentence in this way?
You kill your time which is unwanted.
Is the clause "which is unwanted" correct or not?
I found it in my native english grammar. They said that we can't say like this. Rather we have to say " You kill your time and which is unwanted."

Please edit to explain a bit more; the meaning of the example sentence isn't very clear. Is the time unwanted, or do we mean that the speaker doesn't want the listener to kill time? Also, it's not the point of your question, but the phrase "kill time" doesn't usually take a pronoun like "your" there. "Waste time" does, though. Did this sentence come from somewhere?

@AndyBonner I found it in an English grammar. They said that we can't say like this. Rather we have to say " You kill your time and which is unwanted."

Thanks; please use the "edit" button to add that info into the question itself. If possible, please quote exactly what it says, and mention which book if you can. Based on this information, it seems to be bad advice. The sentence in your comment isn't grammatical without some change. (But the answer to the question in your title is, sure, we can use adjective phrases to modify an object! "I talked to Jim, who was standing over there.")

"You kill your time" is not natural English, so no "native" (Anglophone) grammar book would include anything like that. You should throw whatever your "native english grammar" refers to in the dustbin. It's worthless.

You could (just about) validly say in English: "Smoking is a bad habit. It kills your taste buds, which is unwanted". Note that you can't include the word and before which there.


"You kill your time which is unwanted": There isn't a grammar problem here, but it's un-idiomatic. That is, "words like these can work in ways like this... but we just don't usually use these particular words." We could make a similar sentence that works: "You wash your hair, which is red." We have a whole clause, "which is red," acting like an adjective to modify "hair." The problems with "You kill your time which is unwanted" are:

There is an idiomatic expression "to kill time," and the expression "to waste [someone's] time." This seems to combine them, but we don't usually do that. We don't say "I was just killing my time," but we do say "you're wasting my time." (Also, there's a small difference in meaning. "Killing time" means that you have a lot of free time and little to do in it. "Wasting time" means that you're not spending time on the most important things.)
The clause "which is unwanted" just doesn't make much sense. We don't usually talk about unwanted time. It might mean that the behavior of killing time is unwanted, but if so it's not very clear.
One small problem: in my washing-hair example I added a comma: "You wash your hair, which is red." This means that the adjective phrase is explaining something about the hair. Leaving out that comma might be more appropriate when the adjective phrase identifies the noun, like "Get in the car that has a sign on top."



The sentence that the grammar recommends has bigger problems. "You kill your time and which is unwanted." By adding "and," we've left the adjective clause with no clear antecedent. The "and" would be useful in a compound sentence, like "You feed the cat and the dog," which has one verb and two objects, or "You feed the cat and water the plants," which has two verbs. But this example sentence has only one verb, and we can't turn the adjective phrase into a second object of its own. If we added a word, we could make a grammatical sentence:

You kill your time and that which is unwanted.

Meaning, you kill your time and you also kill those things that are unwanted. This sentence is grammatical, but makes very little sense and is not idiomatic. We could also make the example sentence grammatical by changing a word:

You kill your time and this is unwanted.

This comes closer to making sense, and its meaning would be the same as "You kill your time, which is unwanted." But it still has all the un-idiomatic problems mentioned above.
Unless there's more in the grammar book's context that explains better, I would have to say it's wrong and perhaps a bad source to learn from.
